# override output.elasticsearch.hosts filebeat.yml on wazuh-manager v.4.3.8

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat

I'm trying to override the **filebeat.yml** kubernetes deployment configuration for "**output.elasticsearch: hosts**" but doesn't work and I'm using the **filebeat 7.10.2.**

I used several env variables:

```
  env:
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
      value: 'http://elasticsearch:9200'

  env:
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
      value: 'http://elasticsearch:9200'
```

Doesn't override at all.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment is the wazuh-application v.4.3.8 wazuh-manager and if you have more than one logstash/elasticsearch hosts to add on your filebeat.yml configuration, the only solution that I found is to add the below config and is worked.

**values.yml**

```
elasticsearch:
  hosts: 192.168.22.33:5544', '192.168.10.2:5544
```

**deployment.yml** ### seems that **wazuh-app manager v.4.3.8** doesn't use **ELASTICSEARCH_URL** or **ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS** as a variable inside the docker image, is using **INDEXER_URL**.

```
            - name: INDEXER_URL
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.elasticsearch}}
              value: {{ . | quote }}
```

**filebeat.yml results:**

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ['192.168.10.236:5044', '192.168.10.2:5544']
```